# VBA: Evaluate sumproduct with array and variable

Tags: arrays, excel, evaluate, vba

in my code I need to multiply arrays: one with flags (array "minDiffsArr" with several colums on "1" in needed places) and the other - is the column, where I need to check my condition (only rows with specific value in variable "u")

array minDiffsArr looks like this:

```
1 
 1 
  1
1
1
 1
1
  1
```

...and so on

while range("T3:T37") looks like

```
8
4
6
4
9
1
5
8
```

and variable "u" has values between 1 and 10

I try code:

```
sheets(2).cells(1, 1) = Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(" & sheets(1).Range("T3:T" & linesNum + 2).Value & "=" & u & ")," & wsf.Index(minDiffsArr, 0, i) & ")")
```

however, it fail on Type mismatch error

when I add Watch to my code, it says that both arrays are variant and of the same dimension (1 to 35), so I cannot figure out, what's wrong with the formula

Comment: You can't simply concatenate arrays into a formula string like that.

Comment: Could you tell what exactly is wrong, what and why cannot I concatenate in the formula?
And what is the possible solution to my needs?

Comment: You just can't concatenate an array and a string - it makes no sense. The solution would depend on how `u` and `minDiffsArr` are declared. Specifically, is `u` a 1 dimensional array?

Comment: both are variant. `minDiffsArr` has no other option to correctly contain an array, and `u` is declared as variant to eliminate Type mismatch error.
`u` is just a variable (its meaning is a job's grade) with value from 1 to 10

Comment: How did you populate `u` then? Directly from a range by assigning its Value, or in a loop, or what? I need to know if it's 1 dimensional or 2.

Comment: it's not an array at all. so it's like (1, 1) dimensional - simple variable. it changes its value within a loop, yes.
A couldn't combine VBA array with a worksheet range, so i had to copy my VBA array to a temporary sheet to work with it. 
Not an elegant solution at all, but it works... I simply have no more time to do what I actually want (an elegant solution :)

@Rory, thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Assuming `u` is a one-dimensional array, you can use something like this (you may need to change the separators in the Join statements depending on how you normally enter array constants in a formula):

```
sheets(2).cells(1, 1) = sheets(1).Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(T3:T" & linesNum + 2 & "={" & Join(u, ",") & "}),{" & Join(Application.Transpose(wsf.Index(minDiffsArr, 0, i)), ";") & "})")
```

If `u` is just a one value variable, then:

```
sheets(2).cells(1, 1) = sheets(1).Evaluate("=SUMPRODUCT(--(T3:T" & linesNum + 2 & "=" & u & "),{" & Join(Application.Transpose(wsf.Index(minDiffsArr, 0, i)), ";") & "})")
```